# How to update a single GridView from different forms in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a GridView and 4 other forms. On the button click of one form the GridView row is updating. On the button click of second form another GridView is showing. 
I need to display updated value in single GridView.

```
public void Load_Grid(int counter,string slecteditem,string playername)
{
    DataTable dtable= new DataTable();

    if ((dtable != null) && (dtable.Rows != null) /*&& (dtable.Rows.Count > rowindex)*/)
    {
        int row = dataGridView1.NewRowIndex;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        for (int columnindex = 0; columnindex < dtable.Columns.Count; columnindex++)
        {
            if (dtable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex] != null)
                dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[columnindex].Value = dtable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex].ToString();
        }
        rowindex++;

        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = counter;
        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value = slecteditem;
        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value = playername;

        rowindex++;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Button click present in 4 forms which tries to update Load_Grid function in another form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fm1.Getselected_Controls(this);
    cardobj.Load_Grid(counter, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Gamer3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Form Activated Event. Save your data like Static DataTable and when the anorder forms activated, set new data to grid.

I want to say, You dont have to update all form on the button click.You should update selected form and save your data. when you close the form anorder form will be active and your Form Activeted event trigger.

Define static class

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
     public static int counter  { get; set; }
     public static string selectedItem { get; set; }
     public static string playername { get; set; }
}
```

Add Form Activated event to your forms

```
void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Load_Grid(MyStaticClass.counter, MyStaticClass.selectedItem,MyStaticClass.playername);
}
```

Change your button click event to

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    fm1.Getselected_Controls(this);
    cardobj.Load_Grid(counter, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Gamer3");
    MyStaticClass.counter = counter;
    MyStaticClass.selectedItem= comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MyStaticClass.playername= "Gamer3";
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: I did, look my answer again